# Asset or Item Tracking by Using Block Chain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

Want to create an application for tracking of items which can be recycled.
For that want to use Block chain.I Read some blogs regarding Hyper Ledger.
But didn't have any idea how to proceed.

My Requirement is:
Store all the items in blockchain network.
Fetch all the items from blockchain and dump to database so that the data can be processed further for
manufacturing new product.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Before start using a Blockchain for your project:

- You need first to identify whether you need a Blockchain at all, you can google "when to use Blockchain" you would find a lot of topics about it. you need to answer questions like:

  - is there a need to share the data between multiple parties?
  - do this data need to be private?
  - etc...
- The Hyperledger is not a single project, it is an umbrella for multiple Blockchain projects and tools, you need to pick up the one that matches your requirements. what you've provided doesn't really cover that.

  - the Hyperledger's different projects and tools doesn't really focus on merely save and retrieve data from a Blockchain Data-Structure, its more like building fully working projects and applications on the Blockchain, so you save and process the data on the Blockchain directly.

i think, according to your statement of requirement, that you don't actually need a Blockchain, since you have no problem to save the data in a conventional Database to be processed thereafter.

P.S. in Oracle Database, there is a new table type called Blockchain Table, which is just the Blockchain Data-Structure (without the system protocols), which might be useful for you. https://blogs.oracle.com/blockchain/blockchain-tables-in-oracle-database:-technology-convergence

Comment: I think the data will be shared across multiple parties and also private.

Comment: Example: A mobile manufacturer can use new processor or old processor for manufacturing of mobiles. Let's say one person bought a new mobile and after 6 months somehow that mobile is not working. So here manufacturer can take the processor and can be used in manufacturing of new mobiles. Here we are using the recycled materials in supply chain. For maintaining the data of processor like (date of manufacture/ expiry date/ Used by Govt regulations or not), i think we need a block chain.

Comment: When a mobile is being manufactured, all the details has to be updated in block chain. Again when any old parts/components are beings used to manufacture of mobiles, again all the details has to be updated in block chain.

Comment: problably a Blockchain system would be useful, but this is not enough to know which project to use, under Hperledger, the most known Project is FABRIC, which might be a sutiable choice  to start with, as it covers your needs, from having a consortium to private data between two parties in the same consortium.if you want a Ethereum-like Blockchain system you can head to Hyperledger Burrow also for integration with public Blockchains, in case you want that.